# Trying to run my first Andengine app on device

Tags: android, andengine

```
I tried Little Child's suggestion, but got "Unfortunately V3 has stopped" on the physical device.                       

Here's some of my code:
```

> package org.andengine.ui.activity;
>
> import org.andengine.BuildConfig;
>     import org.andengine.audio.music.MusicManager;
>     import org.andengine.audio.sound.SoundManager;
>     import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.WakeLockOptions;
>     import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.AccelerationSensorOptions;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.IAccelerationListener;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.location.ILocationListener;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.location.LocationSensorOptions;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.orientation.IOrientationListener;
>     import org.andengine.input.sensor.orientation.OrientationSensorOptions;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontManager;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgramManager;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObjectManager;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.view.IRendererListener;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView;
>     import org.andengine.ui.IGameInterface;
>     import org.andengine.util.ActivityUtils;
>     import org.andengine.util.Constants;
>     import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;
>     import org.andengine.util.system.SystemUtils;
>
> import android.content.Context;
>     import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
>     import android.media.AudioManager;
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import android.os.PowerManager;
>     import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
>     import android.view.Gravity;
>     import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
>
> /**
>      * (c) 2010 Nicolas Gramlich
>      * (c) 2011 Zynga Inc.
>      *
>      * @author Nicolas Gramlich
>      * @since 11:27:06 - 08.03.2010
>      */
>     public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends BaseActivity implements IGameInterface, IRendererListener {
>         // ===========================================================
>         // Constants
>         // ===========================================================
>
> ```
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Fields                   
>   // ===========================================================                  
>
>   protected Engine mEngine;                   
>
>   private WakeLock mWakeLock;                 
>
>   protected RenderSurfaceView mRenderSurfaceView;                 
>
>   private boolean mGamePaused;                    
>   private boolean mGameCreated;                   
>   private boolean mCreateGameCalled;                  
>   private boolean mOnReloadResourcesScheduled;                    
>
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Constructors                 
>   // ===========================================================                  
>
>   @Override                   
>   protected void onCreate(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {                 
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreate" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");          
>       }               
>
>       super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);                
>
>       this.mGamePaused = true;                
>
>       this.mEngine = this.onCreateEngine(this.onCreateEngineOptions());               
>       this.mEngine.startUpdateThread();               
>
>       this.applyEngineOptions();              
>
>       this.onSetContentView();                
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public Engine onCreateEngine(final EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {                  
>       return new Engine(pEngineOptions);              
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onSurfaceCreated(final GLState pGLState) {                 
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onSurfaceCreated" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");          
>       }               
>
>       if(this.mGameCreated) {             
>           this.onReloadResources();           
>
>           if(this.mGamePaused && this.mGameCreated) {         
>               this.onResumeGame();        
>           }           
>       } else {                
>           if(this.mCreateGameCalled) {            
>               this.mOnReloadResourcesScheduled = true;        
>           } else {            
>               this.mCreateGameCalled = true;      
>               this.onCreateGame();        
>           }           
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onSurfaceChanged(final GLState pGLState, final int pWidth, final int pHeight) {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onSurfaceChanged(Width=" + pWidth + ",  Height=" + pHeight + ")" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");           
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   protected synchronized void onCreateGame() {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreateGame" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");          
>       }               
>
>       final OnPopulateSceneCallback onPopulateSceneCallback = new OnPopulateSceneCallback() {             
>           @Override           
>           public void onPopulateSceneFinished() {         
>               try {       
>                   if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
>                       Debug.d(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onGameCreated" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");
>                   }   
>
>                   BaseGameActivity.this.onGameCreated();  
>               } catch(final Throwable pThrowable) {       
>                   Debug.e(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onGameCreated failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);    
>               }       
>
>               BaseGameActivity.this.callGameResumedOnUIThread();      
>           }           
>       };              
>
>       final OnCreateSceneCallback onCreateSceneCallback = new OnCreateSceneCallback() {               
>           @Override           
>           public void onCreateSceneFinished(final Scene pScene) {         
>               BaseGameActivity.this.mEngine.setScene(pScene);     
>
>               try {       
>                   if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
>                       Debug.d(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onPopulateScene" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");
>                   }   
>
>                   BaseGameActivity.this.onPopulateScene(pScene, onPopulateSceneCallback); 
>               } catch(final Throwable pThrowable) {       
>                   Debug.e(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onPopulateScene failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);  
>               }       
>           }           
>       };              
>
>       final OnCreateResourcesCallback onCreateResourcesCallback = new OnCreateResourcesCallback() {               
>           @Override           
>           public void onCreateResourcesFinished() {           
>               try {       
>                   if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
>                       Debug.d(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreateScene" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");
>                   }   
>
>                   BaseGameActivity.this.onCreateScene(onCreateSceneCallback); 
>               } catch(final Throwable pThrowable) {       
>                   Debug.e(BaseGameActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreateScene failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);    
>               }       
>           }           
>       };              
>
>       try {               
>           if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {         
>               Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreateResources" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");     
>           }           
>
>           this.onCreateResources(onCreateResourcesCallback);          
>       } catch(final Throwable pThrowable) {               
>           Debug.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onCreateGame failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);          
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onGameCreated() {                  
>       this.mGameCreated = true;               
>
>       /* Since the potential asynchronous resource creation,              
>        * the surface might already be invalid             
>        * and a resource reloading might be necessary. */              
>       if(this.mOnReloadResourcesScheduled) {              
>           this.mOnReloadResourcesScheduled = false;           
>           try {           
>               this.onReloadResources();       
>           } catch(final Throwable pThrowable) {           
>               Debug.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onReloadResources failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);     
>           }           
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   protected synchronized void onResume() {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onResume" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");          
>       }               
>
>       super.onResume();               
>
>       this.acquireWakeLock();             
>       this.mRenderSurfaceView.onResume();             
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onResumeGame() {                   
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onResumeGame" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");          
>       }               
>
>       this.mEngine.start();               
>
>       this.mGamePaused = false;               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean pHasWindowFocus) {                  
>       super.onWindowFocusChanged(pHasWindowFocus);                
>
>       if(pHasWindowFocus && this.mGamePaused && this.mGameCreated) {              
>           this.onResumeGame();            
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public void onReloadResources() {                   
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onReloadResources" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");         
>       }               
>
>       this.mEngine.onReloadResources();               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   protected void onPause() {                  
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onPause" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");           
>       }               
>
>       super.onPause();                
>
>       this.mRenderSurfaceView.onPause();              
>       this.releaseWakeLock();             
>
>       if(!this.mGamePaused) {             
>           this.onPauseGame();         
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onPauseGame() {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onPauseGame" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");           
>       }               
>
>       this.mGamePaused = true;                
>
>       this.mEngine.stop();                
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   protected void onDestroy() {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onDestroy" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");         
>       }               
>
>       super.onDestroy();              
>
>       this.mEngine.onDestroy();               
>
>       try {               
>           this.onDestroyResources();          
>       } catch (final Throwable pThrowable) {              
>           Debug.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onDestroyResources failed." + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')", pThrowable);            
>       }               
>
>       this.onGameDestroyed();             
>
>       this.mEngine = null;                
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public void onDestroyResources() throws Exception {                 
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onDestroyResources" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");            
>       }               
>
>       if(this.mEngine.getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().needsMusic()) {                
>           this.getMusicManager().releaseAll();            
>       }               
>
>       if(this.mEngine.getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().needsSound()) {                
>           this.getSoundManager().releaseAll();            
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   @Override                   
>   public synchronized void onGameDestroyed() {                    
>       if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {             
>           Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onGameDestroyed" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");           
>       }               
>
>       this.mGameCreated = false;              
>   }                   
>
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Getter & Setter                  
>   // ===========================================================                  
>
>   public Engine getEngine() {                 
>       return this.mEngine;                
>   }                   
>
>   public boolean isGamePaused() {                 
>       return this.mGamePaused;                
>   }                   
>
>   public boolean isGameRunning() {                    
>       return !this.mGamePaused;               
>   }                   
>
>   public boolean isGameLoaded() {                 
>       return this.mGameCreated;               
>   }                   
>
>   public VertexBufferObjectManager getVertexBufferObjectManager() {                   
>       return this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager();             
>   }                   
>
>   public TextureManager getTextureManager() {                 
>       return this.mEngine.getTextureManager();                
>   }                   
>
>   public FontManager getFontManager() {                   
>       return this.mEngine.getFontManager();               
>   }                   
>
>   public ShaderProgramManager getShaderProgramManager() {                 
>       return this.mEngine.getShaderProgramManager();              
>   }                   
>
>   public SoundManager getSoundManager() {                 
>       return this.mEngine.getSoundManager();              
>   }                   
>
>   public MusicManager getMusicManager() {                 
>       return this.mEngine.getMusicManager();              
>   }                   
>
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces                   
>   // ===========================================================                  
>
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Methods                  
>   // ===========================================================                  
>
>   private void callGameResumedOnUIThread() {                  
>       BaseGameActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                
>           @Override           
>           public void run() {         
>               BaseGameActivity.this.onResumeGame();       
>           }           
>       });             
>   }                   
>
>   protected void onSetContentView() {                 
>       this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);              
>       this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);                
>
>       this.setContentView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());             
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see Engine#runOnUpdateThread(Runnable)                  
>    */                 
>   public void runOnUpdateThread(final Runnable pRunnable) {                   
>       this.mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(pRunnable);              
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see Engine#runOnUpdateThread(Runnable, boolean)                 
>    */                 
>   public void runOnUpdateThread(final Runnable pRunnable, final boolean pOnlyWhenEngineRunning) {                 
>       this.mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(pRunnable, pOnlyWhenEngineRunning);              
>   }                   
>
>   private void acquireWakeLock() {                    
>       this.acquireWakeLock(this.mEngine.getEngineOptions().getWakeLockOptions());             
>   }                   
>
>   private void acquireWakeLock(final WakeLockOptions pWakeLockOptions) {                  
>       if(pWakeLockOptions == WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON) {             
>           ActivityUtils.keepScreenOn(this);           
>       } else {                
>           final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);            
>           this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(pWakeLockOptions.getFlag() | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, Constants.DEBUGTAG);            
>           try {           
>               this.mWakeLock.acquire();       
>           } catch (final SecurityException pSecurityException) {          
>               Debug.e("You have to add\n\t<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK\"/>\nto your AndroidManifest.xml !", pSecurityException);      
>           }           
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   private void releaseWakeLock() {                    
>       if(this.mWakeLock != null && this.mWakeLock.isHeld()) {             
>           this.mWakeLock.release();           
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   private void applyEngineOptions() {                 
>       final EngineOptions engineOptions = this.mEngine.getEngineOptions();                
>
>       if(engineOptions.isFullscreen()) {              
>           ActivityUtils.requestFullscreen(this);          
>       }               
>
>       if(engineOptions.getAudioOptions().needsMusic() || engineOptions.getAudioOptions().needsSound()) {              
>           this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);         
>       }               
>
>       switch(engineOptions.getScreenOrientation()) {              
>           case LANDSCAPE_FIXED:           
>               this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);        
>               break;      
>           case LANDSCAPE_SENSOR:          
>               if(SystemUtils.SDK_VERSION_GINGERBREAD_OR_LATER) {      
>                   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE); 
>               } else {        
>                   Debug.w(ScreenOrientation.class.getSimpleName() + "." + ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR + " is not supported on this device. Falling back to " + ScreenOrientation.class.getSimpleName() + "." + ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED); 
>                   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
>               }       
>               break;      
>           case PORTRAIT_FIXED:            
>               this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);     
>               break;      
>           case PORTRAIT_SENSOR:           
>               if(SystemUtils.SDK_VERSION_GINGERBREAD_OR_LATER) {      
>                   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);  
>               } else {        
>                   Debug.w(ScreenOrientation.class.getSimpleName() + "." + ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR + " is not supported on this device. Falling back to " + ScreenOrientation.class.getSimpleName() + "." + ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED);   
>                   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
>               }       
>               break;      
>       }               
>   }                   
>
>   protected static LayoutParams createSurfaceViewLayoutParams() {                 
>       final LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);             
>       layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;              
>       return layoutParams;                
>   }                   
>
>   protected void enableVibrator() {                   
>       this.mEngine.enableVibrator(this);              
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#enableLocationSensor(Context, ILocationListener, LocationSensorOptions)}                  
>    */                 
>   protected void enableLocationSensor(final ILocationListener pLocationListener, final LocationSensorOptions pLocationSensorOptions) {                    
>       this.mEngine.enableLocationSensor(this, pLocationListener, pLocationSensorOptions);             
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#disableLocationSensor(Context)}                   
>    */                 
>   protected void disableLocationSensor() {                    
>       this.mEngine.disableLocationSensor(this);               
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#enableAccelerationSensor(Context, IAccelerationListener)}                 
>    */                 
>   protected boolean enableAccelerationSensor(final IAccelerationListener pAccelerationListener) {                 
>       return this.mEngine.enableAccelerationSensor(this, pAccelerationListener);              
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#enableAccelerationSensor(Context, IAccelerationListener, AccelerationSensorOptions)}                  
>    */                 
>   protected boolean enableAccelerationSensor(final IAccelerationListener pAccelerationListener, final AccelerationSensorOptions pAccelerationSensorOptions) {                 
>       return this.mEngine.enableAccelerationSensor(this, pAccelerationListener, pAccelerationSensorOptions);              
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#disableAccelerationSensor(Context)}                   
>    */                 
>   protected boolean disableAccelerationSensor() {                 
>       return this.mEngine.disableAccelerationSensor(this);                
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#enableOrientationSensor(Context, IOrientationListener)}                   
>    */                 
>   protected boolean enableOrientationSensor(final IOrientationListener pOrientationListener) {                    
>       return this.mEngine.enableOrientationSensor(this, pOrientationListener);                
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#enableOrientationSensor(Context, IOrientationListener, OrientationSensorOptions)}                 
>    */                 
>   protected boolean enableOrientationSensor(final IOrientationListener pOrientationListener, final OrientationSensorOptions pLocationSensorOptions) {                 
>       return this.mEngine.enableOrientationSensor(this, pOrientationListener, pLocationSensorOptions);                
>   }                   
>
>   /**                 
>    * @see {@link Engine#disableOrientationSensor(Context)}                    
>    */                 
>   protected boolean disableOrientationSensor() {                  
>       return this.mEngine.disableOrientationSensor(this);             
>   }                   
>
>   // ===========================================================                  
>   // Inner and Anonymous Classes                  
>   // ===========================================================
> ```
>
> }
>
> *************************************StartActivity*******************
>     package com.pearson.lagp.v3;
>     import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
>     import org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine;
>     import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
>     import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
>     import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
>     import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
>     import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
>     import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
>     import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
>
> public class StartActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
>     // ===========================================================
>     // Constants
>     // ===========================================================
>     private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
>     private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;
>     //Getting Our Feet Wet: The Splash Screen 29
>     // ===========================================================
>     // Fields
>     // ===========================================================
>     private Camera mCamera;
>     private BitmapTextureAtlas mTexture;
>     private TextureRegion mSplashTextureRegion;
>     // ===========================================================
>     // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
>     // ===========================================================
>
> public Engine onLoadEngine() {
>     this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH,
>     CAMERA_HEIGHT);
>     return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,
>     CAMERA_HEIGHT),
>     this.mCamera));
>     }
>
> public void onLoadResources() {
>             this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 512, 512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
>
> ```
>       //this.mSplashTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/Untitled.png", 0, 0);              
>
>       this.mSplashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/Untitled.png", 0, 0);
> ```
>
> this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
>     }
>
> public Scene onLoadScene() {
>             this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
>             final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
>             /* Center the splash on the camera. */
>             final int centerX = (int) ((CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2);
>             final int centerY =(int) ((CAMERA_HEIGHT -this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2);
>
> ```
>       /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */                
>       //final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX,centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);             
>       final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX,centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion,mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());                
>
>
>
>       scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);               
>       //Chapter 2 Game 30 Elements and Tools              
>       return scene;
> ```
>
> }
>
> public void onLoadComplete() {
>     }
>     @Override
>     public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         return null;
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onCreateResources(
>             OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> }
>     @Override
>     public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
>             throws Exception {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> }
>     @Override
>     public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
>             OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> }
>
> @Override   public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions)      {       return new LimitedFPSEngine(pEngineOptions, 60);    }
>
> }
>
> *********************AndroidManifest*******************************
>
> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> ```
>
> package="com.pearson.lagp.v3"
>         android:versionCode="1"
>         android:versionName="1.0" >
>
> ```
>   <uses-sdk                       
>       android:minSdkVersion="8"                       
>       android:targetSdkVersion="14" />                        
>
>   <application                        
>       android:allowBackup="true"                      
>       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">                       
>       <activity                       
>           android:name="com.pearson.lagp.v3.StartActivity"                        
>           android:label="@string/app_name" >                      
>           <intent-filter>                     
>               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                        
>
>               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                        
>           </intent-filter>                        
>       </activity>                     
>   </application>
> ```
>
> `

Comment: Post some code, point to line 80 of `BaseGameActivity` :)

Comment: BaseGameActivity is provided by AndEngine itself. I doubt it is problem with BaseGAmeActivity. However, Any class that extends BaseGameActivity should override onCreateEngine. It is probably problem there. try something like `@Override
 public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) 
 {
     return new LimitedFPSEngine(pEngineOptions, 60);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

It very clearly says that you have a `NullPointerException` in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` on line 80 of your code for `BaseGameActivity` class. Look into it :)

```
BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:80)
```

## whenWillPeopleLearnToReadStackTraces?